# android app device owner Provisioning via Cloud Services

Tags: android

As per android documentation by google (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision) Provisioning of device owner can be done via Cloud Services.

I have researched everywhere but not getting any further details. Please let me know how it can be done or where can I find more details.

As I have to do provisioning for large no. of devices so NFC and ABD command provisioning is tedious task.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?